# Automate RestAssured Web Services

Tags: java, rest, testng-eclipse

How to automate the Rest Assured Web Services and all the necessary jar files needed to be in order to not encounter the `java.net.connection` error? Can anyone please guide me for this.

I added the Rest Assured jars from this link
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads.

And added TestNG jars from mvn Repository and using eclipse Luna version 
and yet getting the `java.net.connection`.

Since I am new to this can anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if there is any proxy required?

In case if it is required, you can use below syntax:

```
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().proxy(host, port)
```

Comment: Hi i added this RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().proxy("172.29.67.21",0, "8080"); I am facing a new issue now called java.net.URISyntaxException :Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 8080://172.29.67.21:0:0

Comment: Hi @Nagashri , Can you please verify the syntax of proxy() method, the one I suggested takes 2 param ,host and port, but you are passing three(3) params to it.

Comment: @Nagashri, Did that helped?Let us know if you are facing any issue? or you can accept the answer,so others facing same issue could benefit from it.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, Yes that was helpful.It resolved my issue .Thank you.

Comment: @Nagashri Glad it helped,kindly upvote/accept the answer,so it could help others facing similar issue.